# Automating customisation of Django projects after '$ django-admin.py startproject my_project' with zc.buildout

Tags: python, django, buildout

I have skimmed the official `zc.buildout` documentation and some tuts but I haven't found a clear answer to the following question.

**Suppose I wanted to automate the *following changes* in every Django project(Django1.4) from now on, can all of those changes get executed by merely by a `buildout.cfg` file?**

After doing `$ django-admin.py startproject my_project`, example of *changes* of the default startproject I would implement:

```
$ mkdir ~/path/to/my_project/my_project/db
```

*settings.py:*

```
import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'db/my_project.db'),                      
        'USER': '',                     
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '',                    
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

I currently build and use my own customized distribution of the 1.4 branch of the Django source as a solution but it would be nice to know if I could do it using buildout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not really part of the Buildout set of use-cases.

You want to customize generated code when you start a project, while buildout aims at giving you a reproducible deployment or development environment.

The former *one* developer would use, the latter is aimed at getting multiple developers or multiple production machines up and running with the same software stack.

That said, certainly a buildout recipe can be constructed that writes out new versions of those files when the part is run. For example, using [`collective.recipe.template`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.template) you could specify a template file to be placed in a certain location every time buildout is run. Note that that would *overwrite* those files if they ever changed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martijn's answer: buildout can create directories just fine. Have a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.recipe.mkdir/

That's one of the tasks I regularly use it for (creating a var/log/ for logfiles, a var/sqlite/ dir for the sqlite file, etc.)